# How can I add a new boostrap theme to ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: css, asp.net, webforms

I'm making an ASP.NET Web Forms application, and I'd like to use a boostrap theme I downloaded from bootswatch instead of the default bootstrap theme. When I make a regular ASP.NET MVC application, I'm able to change the bootstrap theme easily using the "bundleconfig.cs" file and "_layout" file, but Web Forms' instead uses a Master Page and a "bundle.config" file and doesn't seem to work the same way.

On my master page I see a line of code that says:

```
<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
```

Which leads me to the bundle.config page where I see:

```
<styleBundle path="~/Content/css">
<include path="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />
<include path="~/Content/Site.css" />
```

I tried editing these links to use a different boostrap theme, but nothing changes.

Comment: Why are you using WebForms?

Comment: @Dai Because I'm remaking a Maths Game application that I previously made using Web Forms and C#, I was told regular MVC wasn't necessary. Would you recommend a different method instead of Web Forms?

Comment: Web Forms is a dying framework. I don't know who told you it "wasn't necessary" to use MVC. Sure, it might not be necessary to use MVC, but that doesn't mean you have to use Web Forms. You've picked an outdated, old fashioned framework which will no longer receive future enhancements. Might want to rethink your strategy. ASP.NET Core MVC is well supported, or you could pick a JavaScript framework (Vue, React, Angular etc) and have that talk to a REST API. And it will be far simpler than Web Forms.

Comment: As far as your current issue, you should just be able to update the bundle config to look at the right file, then do a hard refresh (Control F5) on your browser so that you're not viewing a cached version. And you don't have to use bundling, you can use regular HTML as well if bundling is proving difficult.

Comment: @mason You're right, I'll most likely redo this in regular ASP.NET, I mainly wanted to use C# instead of Javascript since I want to make C# apps. As for your solution, that worked. I was using a cached version and reloading with ctrl + f5 fixed that. Thanks.